# Startup class missing from asp.net mvc visual studio 2013?

Tags: asp.net, startup

I have ***visual studio 2013 express edition*** and when I created the asp.net web application project I am unable to see startup class. I am following tutorials on Identity authentication and authorization and that guy has startup class by default in addition I want to know what that class does ? and how can I get it ?

Comment: If it is missing, just add it in the root directory of the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create One Class With Name Startup this will help you..

```
public class Startup
{
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {
      app.MapSignalR();
   }
}
```